# How to make an sbt task run on under multiple scopes

Tags: scala, sbt

I have written an sbt plugin that generates some sources and resources. It is hard coded to work in the Compile scope.

How can I make it work in the Test scope too, so I can use the plugin when running tests and it will look in and output to the correct folder?

For example, in various points in the code I refer to `resourceManaged in Compile` which relates to `src/main/resources`but when `test` is run, I would like it to be `resourceManaged in Test` when relates to `src/test/resources`.

How do I abstract away the scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a topic discussed in [Plugins Best Practices](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins-Best-Practices.html), specifically in the [Configuration advices](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins-Best-Practices.html#Configuration+advices) section.

#### Provide raw settings and configured settings

If your plugin is `ObfuscatePlugin`, provide `baseObfuscateSettings` that's not scoped in any configuration:

```scala
lazy val baseObfuscateSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
  obfuscate := Obfuscate((sources in obfuscate).value),
  sources in obfuscate := sources.value
)
```

As you can see in the above it's accessing `sources` key, but it's not specified which configuration's source.

#### inConfig

```
override lazy val projectSettings = inConfig(Compile)(baseObfuscateSettings)
```

`inConfig` scopes the passed in sequence of settings into a particular configuration. If you want to support both `Compile` and `Test` out of the box, you can say:

```
override lazy val projectSettings =
  inConfig(Compile)(baseObfuscateSettings) ++
  inConfig(Test)(baseObfuscateSettings)
```