# How do you impose scala code coverage specifically for integration tests?

Tags: scala, sbt, code-coverage, scoverage

Am running the integration test using following sbt command

> sbt clean coverage it:test coverageReport

This command runs integration tests, instruments it and generates report as well.

Build.sbt has following:

```
coverageMinimum in IntegrationTest := 21.0
coverageFailOnMinimum in IntegrationTest := true
```

Output looks like:

```
[info] Statement coverage.: 20.16%
[info] Branch coverage....: 12.00%
[info] Coverage reports completed
[info] All done. Coverage was [20.16%]
```

Output result has 20.16% code coverage but the limits in build.sbt are not enforcing the limit.

If I change build.sbt to following it works:

```
coverageMinimum := 21.0
coverageFailOnMinimum := true
```

Wanted to know what am I missing for specifying limits specifically for Integration tests

Version Information:

sbt : 0.13.17

sbt-scoverage : 1.5.1

Comment: It works with the appropriate setting `coverageFailOnMinimum`, which happens not to be set by default, so what?

Comment: What do you mean by appropriate setting ? Like the same two settings defined within Integration scope doesn’t seem to be recognized. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 5):

The following two workarounds seem to work on my machine (sbt-scoverage 1.5.1, sbt 1.1.1, scala 2.12.5)

**Workaround 1 - Use [`inConfig`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30925566/5205022) to scope to a configuration:**

```
inConfig(IntegrationTest)(ScoverageSbtPlugin.projectSettings),
inConfig(IntegrationTest)(Seq(coverageMinimum := 21, coverageFailOnMinimum := true))
```

Now executing `sbt clean coverage it:test it:coverageReport` throws `Coverage minimum was not reached`.

**Workaround 2 - Modify `coverageMinimum` setting within a custom [command](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Commands.html)**:

```
def itTestWithMinCoverage = Command.command("itTestWithMinCoverage") { state =>
  val extracted = Project extract state
  val stateWithCoverage = extracted.append(Seq(coverageEnabled := true, coverageMinimum := 21.0, coverageFailOnMinimum := true), state)
  val (s1, _) = Project.extract(stateWithCoverage).runTask(test in IntegrationTest, stateWithCoverage)
  val (s2, _) = Project.extract(s1).runTask(coverageReport in IntegrationTest, s1)
  s2
}

commands ++= Seq(itTestWithMinCoverage)
```

Now executing `sbt itTestWithMinCoverage` throws `Coverage minimum was not reached`. Note after executing `itTestWithMinCoverage` the `state` is discarded so `coverageMinimum` should be back to default value, and thus not affect unit tests.

It seems the issue is (besides my lack of understanding how scopes exactly work) [`checkCoverage`](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage/blob/04f78dcdd44a16cd24fae23add71fb36e1b4f4b3/src/main/scala/scoverage/ScoverageSbtPlugin.scala#L126) picks up default value of [`coverageMinimum`](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage/blob/04f78dcdd44a16cd24fae23add71fb36e1b4f4b3/src/main/scala/scoverage/ScoverageSbtPlugin.scala#L30) even after setting `coverageMinimum in IntegrationTest`.

Comment: I tried the inconfig, 1st approach, didn't work for me. have an older version of scala then yours. i defined for test and integration test but it doesn't seem to read it